# Function to PanGesture Error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Getting an error on the last line of code.

> "Cannot assign value of type 'CGPoint' to type 'UIImageView!'"

I tried using `smallDot.center = spawnRandomPosition()`, but when I ran it the smallDot didn't spawn in a random location.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    private var addOne = 0

    func spawnRandomPosition() -> CGPoint  {
        let height = self.view!.frame.height
        let width = self.view!.frame.width

        let randomPosition = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: height),
                                     y: CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: width))
        return randomPosition
    }

    @IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        if let view = recognizer.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                                  y:view.center.y + translation.y)
        }
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

        if (WhiteDot.frame.contains(smallDot.frame) && smallDot.image != nil) {
            smallDot.image = nil;
            addOne += 1
            score.text = "\(addOne)";
            smallDot = spawnRandomPosition() //error here//
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
Your `smallDot.image` might be nil to not toggle function.

[image: Then it should work like this]

***Origin***
The error says that "Cannot assign value of type 'CGPoint' to type 'UIImageView!'" which `CGPoint` is return value of `spawnRandomPosition()` and `UIImageView` is `smallDot`.

Try this: `smallDot.center = spawnRandomPosition()`.

Comment: I said in the question I tried smallDot.center = spawnRandomPosition() , but it didn't spawn the image in a random spot on screen.

Comment: The wrong reason is explained in my answer. The failed action to move smallDot randomly is code logic. What is `smallDot`? what is `WhiteDot`? What you want? move `smallDot` randomly or generate `smallDot` in random position?

Comment: smallDot is the smaller dot and a UIImageView, and whiteDot is the bigger, draggable dot and a UIImageView. I am trying to get the code so when whiteDot is dragged and contains smallDot, the smallDot then disappears and reappears at a random place on the screen, so you can keep on doing it over and over.

Comment: I boldly assume your `samllDot.image` is nil to not toggle the function.

Comment: Deleted that line, but now it spawns it in a random position 2-3 times then image is nowhere to be found on screen.

Comment: This error cause by error of `spawnRandomPosition()`. The random point overflow your screen.

Comment: How is it overflowing my screen? Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Yes it did. You can check return value of `spawnRandomPosition` and compare to yoru screen size.

Comment: What? How would I do that?

Comment: You should confirm yourself first before ask :)

Comment: What? What does that mean

Comment: I mean you should not ask immediately when you have a question, to study and learning, I have answered your question and many other problems